# Quicksort in C: syntax error and undeclared identifiers

Tags: c, function, recursion, quicksort

I have been working on code in C for a recursive quicksort as part of an assignment in my programming class. I have everything written but when I compile I get the following errors:

```
- 1>quick_sort.c(32): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
- 1>quick_sort.c(33): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
- 1>quick_sort.c(35): error C2065: 'right' : undeclared identifier
- 1>quick_sort.c(36): error C2065: 'pivot' : undeclared identifier
- 1>quick_sort.c(39): error C2065: 'right' : undeclared identifier
- 1>quick_sort.c(39): error C2065: 'pivot' : undeclared identifier
- 1>quick_sort.c(40): error C2065: 'right' : undeclared identifier
- 1>quick_sort.c(42): error C2065: 'right' : undeclared identifier
```

Here is my code:

```
/*This code will take input for 10 integers given by the user
into an array and then sort them with a recursive quicksort
function and then print the updated array. */

#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRSIZE 10

void partition (int arr[],int size);
void val_swap (int a, int b);

int main (void){
    int arr[ARRSIZE], left, right, i = 0;

    while(i<ARRSIZE){
        printf("\nInteger value %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    left = 0;
    right = ARRSIZE - 1;

    partition(arr, right-left, left);

    printf("\nThis is your updated array:");
    printf("\n{");
    for(i=0; i<ARRSIZE; i++){
        printf("%d,", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("}");
    return 0;
}    

void partition (int arr[],int size, int left){
    if(size < 2){
        return;
    }
    int pivot = size/2;
    int left = 0, right = size;

    while(left < right){
        while(arr[left] < arr[pivot]){
            left++;
        }
        while(arr[right] > arr[pivot]){
            right++;
        }
        val_swap(arr[left], arr[right]);
    }

    partition(arr,left, 0);
    partition(arr, size-left, left+1);
}    

void val_swap (int a, int b){

    int temp = b;
    b = a;
    a = temp;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:
Okay, I fixed all of my errors, a lot of them were due to visual studio being stupid. My code now kind of works, like when I entered numbers 1-10 as input starting at 10 and counting down to one, the function worked. However, once I gave it more complicated numbers, it was only correctly sorted for about half of the array.

Here is my updated code:

```
/*This code will take input for 10 integers given by the user
into an array and then sort them with a recursive quicksort
function and then print the updated array. */

#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRSIZE 10

void partition (int arr[],int size, int left);
void val_swap (int *a, int *b);

int main (void){
    int arr[ARRSIZE], left, right, i = 0;

    while(i<ARRSIZE){
        printf("\nInteger value %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    left = 0;
    right = ARRSIZE - 1;

    partition(arr, right-left, left);

    printf("\nThis is your updated array:");
    printf("\n{");
    for(i=0; i<ARRSIZE; i++){
        printf("%d,", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("}");
}

void partition (int arr[],int size, int left){
    int pivot, right;
    pivot = size/2;
    right = size;

    if(size < 2){
        return;
    }

    while(left < right){
        while(arr[left] < arr[pivot]){
            left++;
        }
        while(arr[right] > arr[pivot]){
            right--;
        }
        val_swap(&arr[left], &arr[right]);
    }

    partition(arr,left, 0);
    partition(arr, size-left, left+1);
}

void val_swap (int *a, int *b){

    int temp = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = temp;
}
```

Any more suggestions?

Comment: OT: your swap function does nothing: pass refs...

Comment: So you are saying that I should just drop the function in order to avoid the errors?

Comment: no. that's not what I said!

Comment: Yep removed it as quickly as I added it.

Comment: @MitchWheat what do you mean when you say that the function does nothing then?

Comment: He's saying to pass pointers instead of values, otherwise the swap only works inside the function.

Comment: @Nocturno ohhh, that makes sense. I haven't learned pointers yet, so I was trying to avoid using them. would I just point to it by using a &?

Comment: See my answer below to fix your val_swap function. However, this won't completely fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you pass in left, then try to redeclare left.

I think you want `int right = size;`   Note, this is just syntax advice, not whether this gets your qs working :)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant, thanks for that. I forgot to edit it out when I was reworking my code.

I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

your swap function should be like this

```
void val_swap (int* a, int* b){

    int temp = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = temp;
}
```

this loop in function is wrong

```
 while(arr[right] > arr[pivot]){
            right++;
        }
```

`arr[right]` is the last element. By incrementing `right++` you are accesing invalid element. Modified it as below. Please test it

```
while(arr[right] > arr[pivot]){
    right--;
}
```

Also re declaration of variable `left` inside function `partition` has to be removed

Comment: thanks, I didn't even think about why my original code wouldn't work >.<

Answer (score 0):

This fixes just part of your problem:

```
void val_swap (int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I still don't entirely get how to use pointers

Comment: Also, do I have to update my function call to accommodate the change of the function parameters?

Comment: Yes, you must pass pointers as arguments when you call the function. You can either revise your code to use pointers, or use the & operator in front of the arguments you pass. For example you could use `val_swap(&val1, &val2)` if val1 and val2 were integer variables in you code that you want to swap.